Problem with iterations in Pandas DataFrame
I read data from an xlsx-file based on the headers of the first row (contains indexes) and the first column (contains the dates the index was received and its type). In the screenshot you can see the nature of the data organization:

I figured out how to make a pandas DataFrame to read one index. The result is DataFrames of this type:

I can’t figure out how to correctly read all indexes at once, for example using a loop or better list comprehensions.
Here I presented my solution - it is partially working, but I cannot understand how to correctly iterate f'{index_names[1]}_{val} so that it works with all indexes, and not just with one.
I also can’t figure out how to transform the sheet['C' + str(item)] entry so that it iterates over all indexes, and not just one.
characteristic = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700]
index_names = [sheet[1][row].value for row in range(1,sheet.max_row) if sheet[1][row].value != None]

index_list = [pd.DataFrame(
{f'{index_names[1]}_{val}': [sheet['C' + str(item)].value for item in range(1,26) 
            if sheet['A' + str(item)].value == val] 
        for val in characteristic},
    index = ['April 12', 'April 20', 'April 29']
) for _ in range(39)]


Perhaps my code looks cumbersome and could be simplified
UPD: if we will add index_list[0].to_dict('tight') then the result will be as follows:
{'index': ['April 12', 'April 20', 'April 29'],
 'columns': ['Second_index_100',
  'Second_index_200',
  'Second_index_300',
  'Second_index_400',
  'Second_index_500',
  'Second_index_600',
  'Second_index_700'],
 'data': [[0.43927605317127927,
   -0.24029588928209195,
   0.26450969805682434,
   0.18810770500537646,
   0.26586690176009525,
   0.21631310872586834,
   0.32927840726651636],
  [0.16442875037513777,
   0.12442062805633937,
   0.06353459713174614,
   0.14329091121735923,
   0.17469551024592245,
   0.20938555077590043,
   0.17154589574351475],
  [0.4615041268976439,
   0.6488484892496023,
   0.28007883537118355,
   0.5962923255606478,
   0.5924116517116391,
   0.559117121673802,
   0.6458160644845848]],
 'index_names': [None],
 'column_names': [None]}


please provide a [mre] of your DataFrame after import from Excel ([edit] your question with the output of df.to_dict('tight'))

Dear Sir, I edited my question: now there are one DataFrame dict from DataFrames list

Assuming such an input after import (with df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx', index_col=0)):
          First_index  Second_index  Third_index
April 12          NaN           NaN          NaN
100               1.0           2.0          3.0
200               4.0           5.0          6.0
300               7.0           8.0          9.0
400              10.0          11.0         12.0
500              13.0          14.0         15.0
600              16.0          17.0         18.0
700              19.0          20.0         21.0
April 20          NaN           NaN          NaN
100              22.0          23.0         24.0
200              25.0          26.0         27.0
300              28.0          29.0         30.0
400              31.0          32.0         33.0
500              34.0          35.0         36.0
600              37.0          38.0         39.0
700              40.0          41.0         42.0

You could filter the row based on the mask to identify the dates vs future columns, then pivot:
# move index back to column (only if not already a column)
# if already a column, use its name in the following code
# instead of "index"
tmp = df.reset_index()

# identify rows that we be pivoted
# you could also use pd.to_numeric/pd.to_datetime on the "index"
m = tmp['First_index'].isna()

# reshape
out = (tmp[~m].assign(idx=tmp['index'].where(m).ffill())
       .pivot(index='idx', columns='index')
       .rename_axis(None)
      )

# flatten the column MultiIndex
out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')

Output:
          First_index_100  First_index_200  First_index_300  First_index_400  First_index_500  First_index_600  First_index_700  Second_index_100  Second_index_200  Second_index_300  Second_index_400  Second_index_500  Second_index_600  Second_index_700  Third_index_100  Third_index_200  Third_index_300  Third_index_400  Third_index_500  Third_index_600  Third_index_700
April 12              1.0              4.0              7.0             10.0             13.0             16.0             19.0               2.0               5.0               8.0              11.0              14.0              17.0              20.0              3.0              6.0              9.0             12.0             15.0             18.0             21.0
April 20             22.0             25.0             28.0             31.0             34.0             37.0             40.0              23.0              26.0              29.0              32.0              35.0              38.0              41.0             24.0             27.0             30.0             33.0             36.0             39.0             42.0


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample data
data = {
    'a': [np.nan, 1.0, 4.0, 7.0, 10.0, 13.0, 16.0, 19.0, np.nan, 22.0, 25.0, 28.0, 31.0, 34.0, 37.0, 40.0],
    'b': [np.nan, 2.0, 5.0, 8.0, 11.0, 14.0, 17.0, 20.0, np.nan, 23.0, 26.0, 29.0, 32.0, 35.0, 38.0, 41.0],
    'c': [np.nan, 3.0, 6.0, 9.0, 12.0, 15.0, 18.0, 21.0, np.nan, 24.0, 27.0, 30.0, 33.0, 36.0, 39.0, 42.0]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Drop rows with NaN values and reset index
df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
"""
       a     b     c
0    1.0   2.0   3.0
1    4.0   5.0   6.0
2    7.0   8.0   9.0
3   10.0  11.0  12.0
4   13.0  14.0  15.0
5   16.0  17.0  18.0
6   19.0  20.0  21.0
7   22.0  23.0  24.0
8   25.0  26.0  27.0
9   28.0  29.0  30.0
10  31.0  32.0  33.0
11  34.0  35.0  36.0
12  37.0  38.0  39.0
13  40.0  41.0  42.0
"""
# Determine the number of sets dynamically
num_elements = df.size
#print('num_elements : ',num_elements)

num_columns = len(df.columns)
#print('num_columns : ' ,num_columns)

"""
Strategy :

num_elements :  42
num_columns :  3

Now : 42 // (3*2) = 7 
num_sets : 7

So the according to the formulae,
Column reshape must be : num_columns * num_sets = 3*7 = 21  
"""

# Based on the expected output format =>  42/(3*2) = 7 
num_sets = num_elements // (num_columns * 2)  
#print('num_sets :',num_sets)

# Generate new column names dynamically
new_columns = [f'{col}_{i*100}' for col in df.columns for i in range(1, num_sets + 1)]
print(new_columns)
"""
['a_100', 'a_200', 'a_300', 'a_400', 'a_500', 'a_600', 'a_700', 
'b_100', 'b_200', 'b_300', 'b_400', 'b_500', 'b_600', 'b_700', 
'c_100', 'c_200', 'c_300', 'c_400', 'c_500', 'c_600', 'c_700']

"""
"""
According to the formulae,
Column reshape must be : num_columns * num_sets = 3*7 = 21 
"""
# Reshape the DataFrame using numpy
reshaped_array = df.to_numpy().reshape(-1, num_columns * num_sets)
#print(reshaped_array)
"""
[[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17. 18.
  19. 20. 21.]
 [22. 23. 24. 25. 26. 27. 28. 29. 30. 31. 32. 33. 34. 35. 36. 37. 38. 39.
  40. 41. 42.]]
"""
reshaped_df = pd.DataFrame(reshaped_array, columns=new_columns)
#print(reshaped_df )
"""
   a_100  a_200  a_300  a_400  a_500  ...  c_300  c_400  c_500  c_600  c_700
0    1.0    2.0    3.0    4.0    5.0  ...   17.0   18.0   19.0   20.0   21.0
1   22.0   23.0   24.0   25.0   26.0  ...   38.0   39.0   40.0   41.0   42.0

"""
#set index labels based on the number of rows
reshaped_df.index = [f'April_{i+1}' for i in range(reshaped_df.shape[0])]

print(reshaped_df.to_string())

"""
        a_100  a_200  a_300  a_400  a_500  a_600  a_700  b_100  b_200  b_300  b_400  b_500  b_600  b_700  c_100  c_200  c_300  c_400  c_500  c_600  c_700
April_1    1.0    2.0    3.0    4.0    5.0    6.0    7.0    8.0    9.0   10.0   11.0   12.0   13.0   14.0   15.0   16.0   17.0   18.0   19.0   20.0   21.0
April_2   22.0   23.0   24.0   25.0   26.0   27.0   28.0   29.0   30.0   31.0   32.0   33.0   34.0   35.0   36.0   37.0   38.0   39.0   40.0   41.0   42.0

"""

